# Why does my dead simple Django app keep crashing python on my mac 10.6.4?

Tags: django

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404
from django.template.context import RequestContext

from articles.models import Article

def index(request):
    articles = get_list_or_404(Article)
    return render_to_response(
        'articles/index.html',
        {"articles": articles},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
        mimetype="application/xhtml+xml")

def article(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    return render_to_response(
        'articles/article.html',
        {"article": article},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
        mimetype="application/xhtml+xml")
```

models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

import datetime

class Article(models.Model):
    """
    Article model
    """

    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return "%s" % (self.title)

    @property
    def handle(self):
        return self.slug
```

urls

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        r'^$', 
        'articles.views.index',
        name="articles_index"
    ),
    url(
        r'^article/(?P<article_id>\d*)$',
        'articles.views.article',   
        name="article_view",
    ),
)
```

root urls

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from settings import PROJECT_ROOT

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^articles/', include('articles.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': PROJECT_ROOT + "/media"}),
)
```

Would you need to see more?

I had a theory that the word 'Article' might have conflicted with something, tho I tried renaming that to no avail.

This is supposed to be just a little 'play app' that I'm learning on.  But now I'm quite stuck.

Running: python manage.py runserver_plus

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin   (views work ok)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles  (crashes python everytime)

Quite a hair pulling exercise... help very much appreciated

## edit

the error report:

http://dpaste.org/8Fzx/

Thank you!

Comment: Post the traceback that is outputed when the python crashes.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me, but I am not a computer - post the traceback!

Comment: I'm sorry, there is no traceback!! Quite puzzling.  Although, there is the error report that I can 'send to mac'.  One moment.

Comment: Ok, that's added via edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: self referencing template!

Comment: I can no longer see the error report, but a self-referencing template would cause a literal stack overflow, right?